# PHP Undefined index/variable

Tags: php

Error on the first line Undefined index: $pwd
Also undefined variable Under it.
Please show new code Thanks!
The ending of it spits out.

```
$pwd = $_POST['$pwd'];              //Error undefined index: $pwd

if( strlen($pwd) < 8 ) {
        $error .= "Password too short! 
";
}                                     //This line undefined variable
```

Getting error above here******error variable

```
if( strlen($pwd) > 20 ) {
        $error .= "Password too long! 
";
}

if( strlen($pwd) < 8 ) {
        $error .= "Password too short! 
";
}

if( !preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pwd) ) {
        $error .= "Password must include at least one number! 
";
}


if( !preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $pwd) ) {
        $error .= "Password must include at least one letter! 
";
}


if( !preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $pwd) ) {
        $error .= "Password must include at least one CAPS! 
";
}



if( !preg_match("#\W+#", $pwd) ) {
        $error .= "Password must include at least one symbol! 
";
}


if($error){
        echo "Password validation failure(your choice is weak): $error";
} else {
        echo "Your password is strong.";
}
```

Thanks again :D

Comment: Do you really have an element with the name `$pwd`, dollarsign and all ?

Comment: Maybe `$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];` ?

Comment: (Not related to the question:) Furthermore you might consider using "\n" (adding newline character) at the end of your strings instead of really ending with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$pwd = $_POST['$pwd'];` use `$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];`

Comment: Still getting the same index error and the undefined variable.

Comment: Then maybe your password input name is not 'pwd'? Check what is in your $_POST array - print_r($_POST); - one of the keys in that array will be your input password name.

Answer (score 0):

$pwd = $_POST['$pwd'];

I guess this is meant to be:

**$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];**

But it depends on what name the password field have in your form. If the name of the password field on the form is password, then make it $_POST['password']

Answer (score 0):

if you have...

```
<input type="password" name="pwd">
```

then in your php script, you should call it

```
$pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
```

take note of the name attribute.